# Consul and IIS hosted applications

Tags: iis, .net-core, microservices, consul

I'm trying to to use Consul to implement service discovery in a microservice architecture.

I've tried to setup my dotnet core 3.1 application to self register with Consul, and I have 3 VM's running Consul, automatically picking a leader of the 3.

Reading numerous examples online, they all have one thing in common: I need to know the URL of my microservice. Now, using IIS I have 2 options when it comes to hosting; Sites and applications. Sites have a certain URL connected to them (*Example: http://api.microservice1.com*) whereas application use the servername in the URL (*Example: http://webappserver1/microservice1*).

As I have 2 servers (*Let's say webapp01 and webapp02*) I can't know what server the service is running on, and therefore I can't seem to find a solution as to using IIS applications instead of IIS sites. My service would be one of the following routes:

- http://webapp01/microservice1
- http://webapp02/microservice1

Is there a way for me to use IIS applications and not sites? How would I register my microservice with Consul? Perhaps I'm just forced to use IIS sites and not applications?

Comment: As far as I know, IIS only have the web application and virtual directory not the website.  Besides, the url you have used is all setting by yourself by using the IIS site binding feature.  In my opinion, you could modify the domain according to your requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I can edit the binding of my site yes, but that would only allow me to change webapp01, to something like testapp01, but the route for my application would still be http://testapp01/microservice1, and I can't self register the webapp with that route, as I do not know what server the microservice is hosted from.